# Eclipse Internal error makes it impossible to use git

Tags: android, eclipse, git, egit

I am banging my head since yesterday on a problem that popped up after i switched branch on my Android git-managed project, an error pop-up keeps showing making it impossible to use git

[image: pop up error]

Eclipse's log shows :

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2014-11-27 12:05:44.993
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Computing Git status for repository git".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.WorkingTreeIterator.computeHash(WorkingTreeIterator.java:1003)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.WorkingTreeIterator.contentCheck(WorkingTreeIterator.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.WorkingTreeIterator.isModified(WorkingTreeIterator.java:843)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.filter.IndexDiffFilter.include(IndexDiffFilter.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.filter.AndTreeFilter$List.include(AndTreeFilter.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.next(TreeWalk.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.IndexDiff.diff(IndexDiff.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.internal.indexdiff.IndexDiffCacheEntry.calcIndexDiffDataFull(IndexDiffCacheEntry.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.internal.indexdiff.IndexDiffCacheEntry.access$7(IndexDiffCacheEntry.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.internal.indexdiff.IndexDiffCacheEntry$4.run(IndexDiffCacheEntry.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

I tried various attempts to fix it :

- Uninstalling EGIT from Eclipse via MarketPlace the process seems good but after restart, EGIT's still there.
- Deleting it manually by removing it from plugins and featuresfolders as suggested on other posts.
- Starting a fresh Eclipse install and importing git projects, the problem shows off right after the project are added.
- Cloning my GIT repo into another location in a new workspace same problem.
- I couldn't find the exact version of `org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.WorkingTreeIterator` to check on what the NPE happens

It seems to like if my GIT repo was corrupted, any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**
I don't know if it's relevant but here's Session data :

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.6.0_43
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=fr_FR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -data D:\Development\workspace -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
```

Comment: How exactly would your eclipse corrupt your git if all you did was switch to a different branch of the project?

Comment: I have no idea. i just suspect it, since the problems seems to come when i import the projects into eclipse

Comment: Switching back to the main repo doesn't do anything either? To check if eclipse is working properly or that the repo just isn't reachable from eclipse.

Comment: It doesn't help it keeps showing the same error prompt

Comment: I guess all that's really left is trying it with a fresh install of eclipse to see if it's not just some obscure option in your config?

Comment: What version of JGit and EGit do you have installed?

Comment: JGIT and EGIT version : 3.4.1.201406201815-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally get rid of the problem, i don't know what was exactly the problem but i guess it must be some kind of inconsistencies between Eclipse EGIT plugin and Git repository. 
After staging/committing/pushing changes via git command line, the exception stopped showing in Eclipse, i know it's not a very explicit Problem/Solution but i'll let here, it may help or put someone with the same problem's symptoms on track .

Answer (score 5):

This solution worked for me 
right click on project 
go to Team - select Disconnect.
Now refresh Project. commit all ur changes to branch.
restart eclipse 
Problem solved.

if you want to share the project again. you can share it by following same steps
Team - Share Porject.

Answer (score 1):

1. Take a backup of your files
2. Reset them to head revision.
3. Right click on project `select team`->select->share project->dialogue box appears with local location of project select and say OK.
4. Now right click on project->team->disconnect.
5. Refresh your 
   project.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in Eclipse. Updating submodules worked around the issue for me.
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=450567

Answer (score 0):

I was launching eclipse.exe on Windows 10, and it was defaulting to **Compatibility Mode** for Windows 7. I unchecked that, and the error went away.

Source: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471027